# guards wont stop killing me in skyrim and i need help?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If i go to markarth my bounty is over 1000. I have yet to do the forsworn mission, and I don't even know what I did to receive that bounty. Still the guards keep killing me even if I just stand there when my weapon is sheathed. I just want to pay and do the other 4 missions i have there right now.

Comment: Maybe the guards and the crime systems are bug. Use console commands if you're on PC.

Answer (score 1):

Fast travel Markarth Stables, a guard will run to you and you will be able to talk to him.

If that doesn't work, make your way into Talos shrine in the city and try to talk with the guards.

Comment: why am i get downvoted, lol?

Comment: i dont know why you got down voted, i certainly appericate your answer , but thank you i tried that but they just kept killing me so what i did is had him chase me to the river by the mine since he wont go in there he actually started talking to me and gave me the option for jail or die and not surrender. so i did jail time. it was getting annoying, so when i do do this forsworn mission im going to have to deal with that all over... thats lame... thanks again!